# Fastest way to import SPSS data into R as dataframe

Tags: r, spss

I need to import an SPSS .sav file into R every day as a data frame without value labels. The file is 120,000+ obs and growing.  This process is getting incredibly slow, so I want to make sure I'm using the fastest possible method. I've been playing around with the functions in foreign, haven, and memisc. I'm working with RDS if that makes a difference.

Edit: My file is 126343 x 33067 and 12.1 GB.I'm just simply running the following code:

```
library(haven)
data <- read_sav(file)
```

I can't share this file, but to attempt to replicate, I did:

```
library(haven)
n <- 126343
exd <- data.frame(c(replicate(2000, sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE),
                              simplify = FALSE),
                    replicate(1306, runif(n),
                              simplify = FALSE)))
dim(exd)
## [1] 126343    3306
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".sav")
write_sav(exd, tmp)
system.time(exd2 <- read_sav(tmp))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  173.34   13.94   187.66
```

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up saving my files as csvs and using the data.table fread function:

Answer (score 1):

120000 isn't very big. Unless you have a very low resource system I wouldn't expect this to be much of a bottleneck at all. On my mid-range laptop it takes just a few seconds to read a 122000 X 150 `.sav` file:

```
library(haven)
n <- 122000
exd <- data.frame(c(replicate(50, sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE),
                              simplify = FALSE),
                    replicate(100, runif(n),
                              simplify = FALSE)))
dim(exd)
## [1] 122000    150
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".sav")
write_sav(exd, tmp)
system.time(exd2 <- read_sav(tmp))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  1.913   0.096   2.015
```

Since I can't reproduce the problem as you've described it you should provide more details to make it clearer what the issue is. If you show the code and (a subset or simulation of) the data you're working with you might get some help identifying the likely bottleneck.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't specific enough, please see my updated question.

Comment: I would agree that it could be your resources that are the bottle neck, If you do not have enough physical memory available it will swap to disk (slower). What OS and how much RAM do you have? can you clean up some of the memory that is being used?  ls() will list your variables rm(var) will clear variable you should run gc() to garbage collect

Answer (score 0):

The haven package (part of the tidyverse) would be my choice. But have not used it on datasets as big

https://github.com/tidyverse/haven

Comment: I tried read_sav from haven earlier today, but it wasn't done importing after an hour and a half and I had to exit the RDS.

Comment: @Jklein what does `RDS` have to do with it? What code are you actually running?

Comment: That is surprising, haven readme, indicates that it should be 4x faster for some spss files , but others load slower, not sure about the reason. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/haven/versions/0.2.0/readme